# using vml for html creates issues with inline css

Tags: html, css, vml

Using html code along with VML(for background images) to send newsletters to the customers.  Before using VML inline CSS worked fine, but when VML is added to the code, it stopped working in OUTLOOK.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width:50" />

    <title> Transaction Alert from KVB </title>

</head>

<body>

    <div>

        <table style="border:1px solid black" width="600" height="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

            <tr>
                <!-- Backup background color is #DDDDDD -->
                <td style="background-image: url('http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/bg.jpg');" background="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/bg.jpg" valign="top" align="left">

                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:rect style="width:600px;height:600px;" strokecolor="none">
      <v:fill type="tile"  src="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/bg.jpg"  color="#7bceeb"/></v:fill>
   </v:rect>
   <v:shape id="theText" style="position:absolute;width:600px;height:600px;">
   <![endif]-->

                    <a href="http://www.kvb.co.in/">

                        <center><img src="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/1111.png" width="600" height="300"></center>

                    </a>

                    <div STYLE="color: WHITE; background-color: #00844A; border: 1px solid white; padding: 15px;border-radius: 20px; border-collapse: separate;">

                        <center>
                            <font face="Verdana">A.MESSAGE</center>
                        </font>
                    </div>

                    <p>
                        <font face="Verdana" size="1">
                            <center>Note: If the transaction is not done by you, please contact our Helpline at the earliest.</font>
                        </center>
                    </p>

                    <br><br><br><br>

                    <a href="http://www.kvb.co.in/">

                        <center><img src="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/mpay_new.png" width="600" height="130"></center>

                    </a>

                    <br>

                    <br>

                    <p>
                        <font face="Verdana">With Regards,</font>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <font face="Verdana">Karur Vysya Bank.</font>
                    </p>

                    <hr width=1 00%>

                    <br>

                    <div style="max-width:auto; word-wrap:break-word;">
                        <font face="Verdana">This E-Alert was automatically generated by the system. Please do not reply to this mail. For any further clarifications, kindly contact your Home branch/our Helpline Number 1860 200 1916 (Local call charges applicable).</font>
                    </div>

                    <p>
                        <font face="Verdana"> This E-Alert was automatically generated by the system. Please do not reply to this mail. For any further clarifications, kindly contact your Home branch/our Helpline Number 1860 200 1916 (Local call charges applicable)</font>
                    </p>

                    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
     </v:shape>
     <![endif]-->

                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>

    <body>

</html>
```

I am especially getting issue at this block

```html
<div STYLE="color: WHITE; background-color: #00844A; border: 1px solid white; padding: 15px;border-radius: 20px; border-collapse: separate;">

    <center>
        <font face="Verdana">A.MESSAGE</center>
    </font>
</div>
```

Please help me out, I am adding the screenshot for your reference
[image: Outlook issue]

Comment: You need to be clearer about what the problem is and what the expected output looks like. Use JSFIDDLE if possible to show the expected result in a normal browser and a screenshot of how it differs in Outlook. The smaller the code needed to demonstrate the problem, the more likely somebody will help you.

Comment: border-collapse: separate; only applies to tables not divs, looks fine here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZaYrO

Comment: Yes, but it creating issues in outlook only. In browsers, gmail and yahoo it is working fine. I have edited my question to add the screenshot which shows the issue in OUTLOOK

Comment: Are you making a scamming mail or something lol?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by removing the div tag and replacing it with a table

I am providing the complete code

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
      <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">  
       <head>                
       <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width:50"/>
        <title> Transaction Alert from KVB </title>
         </head>
          <body>
            <div>             
    <table  style="border:1px solid black" width="600" height="800" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  >
     <tr>
    <!-- Backup background color is #DDDDDD -->
                  <td  style="background-image: url('http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/bg.jpg');" background="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/bg.jpg"  valign="top"   align="left" >
         
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                      <v:rect style="width:600px;height:900px;" strokecolor="none">
                                      <v:fill type="tile"  src="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/bg.jpg"  color="#7bceeb"/></v:fill>
                                       </v:rect>
                                      <v:shape id="theText" style="position:absolute;width:600px;height:900px;z-index:3;">
                        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
 
                                      <![endif]-->
       
       


            
                      <a href="http://www.kvb.co.in/">
                      <center><img src="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/1111.png" width="600" height="300"></center>
                      </a>

                <!------THIS IS THE PART WHERE I HAVE DONE THE MODIFICATION-->
                      <table width = "100%"  border-collapse: separate;    border-spacing: 0;>
               
                            <td STYLE="color: WHITE; background-color: #00844A; border: 1px solid white; padding: 15px;border-radius: 20px; border-collapse: separate;">

                                      <center><font face="Verdana">A.MESSAGE</center></font></td>
        </table>

                     <p><font face="Verdana" size ="1"><center>Note: If the transaction is not done by you, please contact our Helpline at the earliest.</font></center></p>

                       <br><br><br><br>

                       <a href="http://www.kvb.co.in/">

                       <center><img src="http://www.kvbsmart.com/mail_img/mpay_new.png" width="600" height="130"></center>

                      </a>

                       <br>

                          <br>

                           <p><font face="Verdana">With Regards,</font></p>

                                  <p><font face="Verdana">Karur Vysya Bank.</font></p>

    
                             <hr width = 100%>

                            <br>

                           <div style="max-width:auto; word-wrap:break-word;"><font face="Verdana">This E-Alert was automatically generated by the system. Please do not reply to this mail. For any further clarifications, kindly contact your Home branch/our Helpline Number 1860 200 1916 (Local call charges applicable).</font></div>

              




              
                                 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                 </v:shape>
                                   <![endif]-->  
     

                                               </td></tr>


                </table></div>


                                                         <body></html>
```